# How can I replace a URL prefix using SQL?

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL database, I have a SQL table where there is a column that stored the URL of some images that I am displaying on my website. The URL field is something like `http://some_domain/some_thing`

I need to replace all of them with something like `https://some_domain/some_thing`

I can write a C# script to do the same and write the required regex in C#. Does anyone know how to do this kind of replacement in SQL Server.

Comment: This isn't word replacement. You ask how to replace one prefix with another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to search for all entries that have an `http://` prefix and then replace it, eg:

```
UPDATE MyTable
set ImageUrl=REPLACE(ImageUrl,'http://','https://')
where ImageUrl like 'http://%'
```

The `WHERE` clause ensures that only entries with `http://` are processed and allows the query to take advantage of possible indexes on the image field. `LIKE 'abc%' is essentially a range search that matches values between` abc`and the next entry after the prefix, ie`abd`

Comment: Up voted and deleted my answer, since yours is far more elegant and fault proof

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish I could have seen this answer earlier. I wrote a script in C#, that goes over all the URL in the database and does a regex based string replacement in C#.

Comment: Cheers, this was useful. I found wrapping the where clause value with '%http://%' worked better in my case. Maybe SQL version?

Comment: No, I forgot the trailing `%`.  There's no need for a *leading* `%`. That prevents the database engine from using any indexes on the column. The clause `LIKE 'ABC%'` is essentially a range query overing all items between `ABC` no matter how long they are and `ABD`. SQL Server is smart enough to convert that to a range query and use an index